# "Collection is not defined" when trying to create a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, constants, client

I am new to discord.js and have been following a youtube tutorial (linked here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22BFybCwSFU&list=PL-Ux9UcyEUaNxn_TbByomT-01UUKHOoD1&index=3&ab_channel=Exane) that uses an outdated version of discord.js (something that has given me some problems)

Their code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js') 
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs")
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

On the final line (line 5), when I try to input new Discord.Collection(); I am given the ReferenceError: Discord is not defined, and yet when I remove "Discord." from the line, I am given the ReferenceError: Collection is not defined.

I have changed my code according to comments from people also struggling when using a more updated version of discord.js and node.js, but so far have found no fix. My code will be put below this and I'm really sorry if it's a dumb/obvious fix, thank you so much for reading!

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, CommandInteractionOptionResolver } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({ intents: ["DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const fs = require("fs")
bot.Commands = new Collection();
```

( I think that I am supposed to define the first "const" variable with the Name "Discord" but when I try to do this I am greeted with the same errors )

edit: I forgot to mention before that before this I had to add (steal) code to the first line to allow me to add intents when creating a new client, as in older versions you previously didn't need to add intents here, yet my code would not function without it in discord.js version 13.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube video author you are telling us about is using `Discord.Collection()` because it's the way "you say" you want to create `discord.js` collection. If you don't want to use it and just use `Collection()`, you have to define it using `const { Collection } = require('discord.js')` first