# Creating discord bot js - Collections is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am new to coding a discord bot with JS and I am not sure why I am getting an error when I am trying to make a collection for a library of other .js files. I am instead greeted with the image below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vUK1.png)

Broken code:
https://sourceb.in/x2EFkdb5sV

Line 14.

I tried defining Collections using another question on this site with similar problems:["Collection is not defined" when trying to create a discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048255/collection-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-create-a-discord-bot) .

It wasnt the answer I was looking for as it deviates from making a collection.

Comment: Hi! As yacine said, Your only and only problem is an "s"! All other lines of code is ok, no worries. Try replacing `Collection` instead of `Collections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must require the class Collection from discord.js to be able to use the Collection class.

At the beggining of your code, change `const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');` to `const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require('discord.js');`

In addition, its `Collection`, not `Collections` (there is no s). So you will have to write `new Collection();` instead of `new Collections();`.